# value already exist using bootstrapvalidation on codeigniter if value already exist

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, bootstrapvalidator

I Tried using bootstrap validation for a project with CodeIgniter framework , but when I insert the current value ' ID ' validation does not work when there is value already exist in the database.

> ITS SOLVED

this my controllers

```
public function check_user()
{
    $id= $this->input->post('id');
    $result= $this->mcrud->check_user_exist($id);
    if($result)
    {
        echo "false";

    }
    else{

        echo "true";
    }
}
```

this my models

```
public function check_user_exist($id)
{
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $query= $this->db->get('tbdetail');
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and this my javascipt for validation

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#defaultForm').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },      

        fields: {
            id: {
                    row: '.col-md-3',
                        message: 'ID Tidak Valid',
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'ID tidak boleh kosong'
                                },
                            remote: {
                                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/instrument/detailalat/check_user',
                                type:'POST',
                                message: 'ID sudah ada'
                                }                           
                        }
                },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i notice, you are not passing any value through post using `data`,
So try this,

```
    id: {
          row: '.col-md-3',
          message: 'ID Tidak Valid',
          validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                     message: 'ID tidak boleh kosong'
                },
                remote: {
                     url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/instrument/detailalat/check_user',
                     type:'POST',
                     message: 'ID sudah ada',
                     data: function(validator) {
                          return {
                               id: $('[name="name of the id in your form"]').val(),
                          };
                     },
               }                           
         }
    },
```

For more information see [here](http://formvalidation.io/validators/remote/)

Comment: thanks @Niranjan N Raju,  I tried but it was not working . what wrong with the controller and the model ??

Comment: check the console, is the `id` passed to controller?? echo the id in controller and see what you are getting there.

Comment: Also instead of `return $query->result();` try with, `return $query->num_rows();`

Comment: did u check with that??

Comment: is the value going to controller??

Comment: whats wrong with my controllers? result validation false

Comment: are you able to pass the value?? echo the id in controller see in console.

Comment: it solved thanks @Niranju, there are script less complete i change controllers with ,   
`$id= $this->input->post('id');
$result= $this->mcrud->check_user_exist($id);
if($result==0)
        {
    $isAvailable = true;  
   
        }
        else{
   
   $isAvailable = False;
       }

  echo json_encode(array(
   'valid' => $isAvailable,
   ));`